# Raising a ValidationError of a Date in Django

Tags: django

I want to raise a validation error in my form. If date is invalid, raise my own message instead of Django's default message. The form is long and SO does not allow long CODE ONLY on a question so I only included relevant details

```
class ApplicantForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Applicant

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['birth_date'].widget=forms.widgets.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'text'})

    def clean_birth_date(self, *args, **kwargs):
        birth_date = self.cleaned_data.get("birth_date")

        date_valid = False
        birth_date = str(birth_date)
        year = birth_date[0:4]
        month = birth_date[5:7]
        day = birth_date[8:10]

        # Check if birth_date is a proper date
        birth_date = year.zfill(4) + month.zfill(2) + day.zfill(2)

        print("TEST")
        try:
            birth_date = datetime.strptime(birth_date, '%Y%m%d')
            date_valid = True
        except ValueError:
            date_valid = False

        if not date_valid:
            print("TEST")
            raise forms.ValidationError("Something Message Here.")

        return birth_date
```

model:

```
birth_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, null=False)
```

If the date is valid, I can see the TEST in my terminal. That means my clean function works(I think). However, if invalid like 123, or Feb 30, the first print("TEST") does not print in terminal thus, does not reach try except block. Then django returns its default message. If you have an idea, please let me know.

Comment: try using a debugger

Comment: as far as I know, it should handle the form validation by itself. You do not need to override the clean method for that.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 try:
     birth_date = datetime.strptime(birth_date, '%Y%m%d')
    date_valid = True
 except AttributeError:  # this may not work for some cases
      date_valid = False


 or 

 try:
     birth_date = datetime.strptime(birth_date, '%Y%m%d')
    date_valid = True
 except:
      date_valid = False
```

Comment: The same. When I enter an invalid date, the first print("TEST") is not even printing, so it does not reach try except block.

Answer (score 0):

The TESt is not printing because of this line

`birth_date = self.cleaned_data.get("birth_date")`

try overriddding the clean method and write your function there.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, I also have other clean_FOO method that is almost identical to my question and they are returning the correct ValidationError message.